# Laravel - Use default value if input is null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel, if I've set a default value of 0 for all my integers, how can I get it to just go with its default if the request is null?

I've tried:

```
$property->bedrooms = $request->input('bedrooms', 0);
```

But it still just tries to set it as null and throws an error, as I'm assuming that's just for if the value doesn't exist at all.

Of course, I could go:

```
if($request->bedrooms){
    $property->bedrooms = $request->bedrooms;
}else{
    $property->bedrooms = 0;
}
```

...but that seems rather verbose.

Is there a neater solution I'm missing? Default values are sorta useless if you need to use an if/else every time anyway, surely.

Comment: If you don't want to remove the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware you could just use a one liner ternary statement, like:`$property->bedrooms = $request->bedrooms ?: 0;`

Comment: Cheers Aaron! I guess Rob's is _technically_ the most correct answer but that shorthand is real handy too.

Comment: Yeah, I agree! Just a trick if you need to use that middleware in other parts of your application :)

Comment: This should work with decent PHP versions:
`$property->bedrooms = $request->input('bedrooms') ?? 0;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4, they added the **ConvertEmptyStringsToNull** middleware which essentially overrides the $request->input() default value as if the field is not present in the request, it will add it to the request with a value of **null**.

$request->input(field, default value) will work again if you comment out the middleware in **app\Http\kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        // \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Ahhh yes. Thanks for that, Rob!